# Generic type constraint constructor limitation, need advice

Tags: c#, .net, generics, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to instantiate an object in the constructor of a class based on what type parameter was passed to create the instance of said class.

```
public class DefaultController<TEntity, TStrategy> : ApiController, IDisposable where TEntity : class, IEntity where TStrategy: BaseStrategy<TEntity>
{

    public IStrategy<TEntity> strategy { get; set; }


    public DefaultController()
    {
        //strategy = ??
    }
}
```

And here's `BaseStrategy`

```
public abstract class BaseStrategy<TEntity> : IStrategy<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
{

    private IRepository<TEntity> repository;

    public BaseStrategy(IRepository<TEntity> _repository)
    {
        repository = _repository;
    }

    //implements a bunch of methods...
}
```

As you can see, `BaseStategy` has no parameter-less constructor which makes it impossible to use the `new()` generic constraint in `DefaultController`

What I'm trying to achieve is, from a class extending `DefaultController`, configure which strategy to use

```
public class UserController : DefaultController<User, GreatStrategy<User>>
{
    //   GreatStrategy extends BaseStrategy
}
```

Any workaround to make the magic work or another approach perhaps ?

Thanks.

Comment: I just put in the constraint `where TStrategy : BaseStrategy<TEntity>, new()` on `DefaultController<,>` and it works fine for me with your current code. I could then write `strategy = new TStrategy();`. Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @Enigmativity If you reproduced the example with `UserController`, in there you will get the error: `must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TStrategy'`. Which comes back the the issue I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason DefaultController needs a parameterless constructor? You could try:

```
public DefaultController(IStrategy<IEntity> strategy) : base(strategy)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

And then in your UserController constructor:

```
public UserController() : base(new GreatStrategy<User>()) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Are you using IoC in your application? If so, you can register your strategies and inject them into the controller constructors so that you don't have to spin up a new Strategy in the base constructor call.

Hope this gives you some guidance moving forward.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I ended up modifying contsructors for both DefaultController and all the other controllers extending it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying the constructors of the default controller and of all controllers extending it as such:

```
    public DefaultController(IStrategy<TEntity> _strategy)
    {
        strategy = _strategy; // 'strategy' is a local member implementing IStrategy...
    }
```

And a controller extending default controller has a constructor like:

```
public class UserController : DefaultController<User>
{
    public UserController()
        : base (new GreatStrategy<User>(new Repository<User>()))
    {
        //GreatStrategy extends BaseStrategy...
    }

}
```